# Stateless function components cannot be given refs. But I'm trying to give it to a class component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following class:

```
class ModelList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.stickySidebar = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      bottomBorder: false
    };
  }

  ...

  render() {
    const {
      title,
      button,
      navHeight,
      footerHeight,
      children,
      ...props
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <ModelListWrapper
        {...props}
        navHeight={navHeight}
        footerHeight={footerHeight}
        bottomBorder={this.state.bottomBorder}
      >
        <ModelListHeader>
          {title && <H3>{title}</H3>}
          {button && <Button {...button} color="link" size="sm" />}
        </ModelListHeader>
        <SidebarContainerSticky
          id="sticky-sidebar-model-list"
          ref={this.stickySidebar}
          navHeight={navHeight}
          footerHeight={footerHeight}
        >
          {children}
        </SidebarContainerSticky>
      </ModelListWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to pass the `this.stickySidebar` as a ref into the `SidebarContainerSticky` component. However, I'm getting the stateless function components cannot be given refs error. I've refactored what used to be a stateless component into a class component, like so:

```
class SidebarContainerSticky extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navHeight, footerHeight, ...props } = this.props;

    return (
      <div
        {...props}
        data-ut="sidebar-container-sticky"
        style={{ height: `calc(100vh - ${navHeight + footerHeight}px)` }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withStyleClassName(
  SidebarContainerSticky,
  "sidebarContainerStickyClassName"
);
```

however, I'm still getting the same error. Is there even a higher hurdle than just making the component into a class-based one or am I missing something here?

Comment: it should work now, did you recompile your code ?

Comment: I did, but it's still not working :/

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Any other thoughts?

Comment: no I tried with this simple example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wy16pk and it works well, don't know what is the problem with `SidebarContainerSticky`...

Comment: Ok, I think I got what the issue was. `SidebarContainerSticky` was being exported while being wrapped inside a HOC and the refs weren't getting forwarded. I've updated the HOC to use forwarded refs, so that seems to be taken care of.

The new issue now, however, is that calling `this.stickySidebar.current.clientHeight` returns `undefined`. Any ideas for what might be the reason for that?

Comment: `clientHeight` will only work if you put the `ref` on a DOM node but not on a React element. Maybe you will need `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.stickySidebar.current).clientHeight` but it's not recommended to use`findDOMNode` so maybe the good solution is to forward ref to the first DOM node child of `SidebarContainerSticky`

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. I ended up using React.forwardRef, will add response shortly.